# Baire theorem in function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^1$ is continuous over each variable. Prove that $f$ can not be discontinuous at every point.

I am thinking on this problem couple days and I guess that key to this problem is Baire theorem but I don't know how to use it correctly.

Can anyone show a full proof. I would be very grateful!

Comment: the proof that the set of discontinuities of a separately continuous function in question can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets is highly non-trivial. Once you have this, the Baire Category Theorem solves your problem immediately.

Comment: @akech, I know that fact since I used it in proving one of my problems. But can you show a solution to above problem?